# ¿Como puedo simular un rebote realista (Dependiendo de angulos) en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ecmascript-6

En javascript tengo una clase llamada Ball, esta lleva como parametros, los mismos parametros basicos de la funcion arc del canvas.

Es decir, x,y,r,anguloInicial,anguloFinal, el ultimo parametro como es totalmente opcional no lo agregue.

Hice una colision basica para que la pelota rebote correctamente contra los bordes del canvas, sin embargo... Y si necesito que la pelota colisione no solo con los bordes del canvas si no que también colisione de manera realista contra otros objetos, (Por ejemplo un rectangulo) y cambie la trayectoria correctamente dependiendo del angulo en que fue golpeada...

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?, se que se debe usar las funciones sin y cos, pero ¿con que parámetro las uso?, cabe destacar que la forma en la que la pelota se mueve es lineal (ax) y depende de un parámetro de la clase llamado dir, este es un JSON que se ve así:

```
this.dir = {x: 0, y: 0}
```

inicialmente ambas direcciones son cero, también existe el parámetro de velocidad en la clase que será el mismo para ambas direcciones, cuando el usuario da click en el canvas cambian ambas direcciones a 1, haciendo que la pelota pueda comenzar a moverse.

por lo que la formula que empleo para que se mueva la pelota es:

```
this.x += this.dir.x * this.speed;
this.y += this.dir.y * this.speed;
```

Entonces para cambiar la trayectoria de la pelota de manera correcta al colisionar con otro elemento en determinado angulo, ¿Qué formula o metodo para simular esto podría usar?

Mi código:

```js
window.onload = () => {

 let arkanoid, ball;

 function start() { ball.start(start) }

 function collision(...objects) {

  let [obj, obj2] = objects;

  if (obj.type === "ball") {

   if (obj.right >= obj2.left && obj.left <= obj2.right &&
    obj.bottom >= obj2.top && obj.top <= obj2.bottom) {

    obj.dir.y *= -1;
    return true;

   } else {

    return false;

   }

  } else {

   if (obj.right >= obj2.left && obj.left <= obj2.right && obj.bottom >= obj2.top && obj.top <= obj2.bottom) {

    obj2.dir.y *= -1;
    return true;

   } else {

    return false;

   }

  }

 }

 function degreesToRadians(degrees) {

  const radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degrees;
  return radians;

 }

 class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
  }
 }

 class Bar {

  constructor(arkanaid, ctx, x, y, w, h, speed = 1) {
   this.arkanaid = arkanaid;
   this.ctx = ctx;
   this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
   this.speed = speed;
   this.w = w;
   this.h = h;
   this.type = "rect"
  }

  get left() {
   return this.pos.x;
  }

  get right() {
   return this.pos.x + this.w;
  }

  get top() {
   return this.pos.y;
  }

  get bottom() {
   return this.pos.y + this.h;
  }

  draw(color = "#ffffff") {
   this.ctx.save();
   this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
   this.ctx.fillRect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.w, this.h);
   this.ctx.restore();
  }

 }

 class Ball {

  constructor(ctx, x, y, r, speed = { x: 1, y: 1 }, color = "#ffffff") {
   this.ctx = ctx;
   this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
   this.dir = new Vector(0, 0);
   this.speed = speed;
   this.r = r;
   this.color = color;
   this.type = "ball";
  }

  get left() {
   return this.pos.x - this.r;
  }

  get right() {
   return this.pos.x + this.r;
  }

  get top() {
   return this.pos.y - this.r;
  }

  get bottom() {
   return this.pos.y + this.r;
  }

  start(callback) {

   this.dir.x = Math.floor(-Math.random()) * Math.floor(-Math.random() * 2);
   this.dir.y = Math.floor(-Math.random()) * Math.floor(-Math.random() * 2);
   this.ctx.canvas.removeEventListener("click", callback);

  }

  wallCollision() {

   if (this.pos.x - this.r <= 0 || this.pos.x + this.r >= this.ctx.canvas.width) {

    this.dir.x *= -1;
    this.pos.x += this.dir.x;

   } else if (this.pos.y - this.r <= 0 || this.pos.y + this.r >= this.ctx.canvas.height) {

    this.dir.y *= -1;
    this.pos.y += this.dir.y;

   }

  }

  move() {

   this.pos.x += this.dir.x * this.speed.x;
   this.pos.y += this.dir.y * this.speed.y;

  }

  draw() {
   this.ctx.save();
   this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   this.ctx.beginPath();
   this.ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, 0, degreesToRadians(360));
   this.ctx.closePath();
   this.ctx.fill();
   this.ctx.restore();
  }

 }

 class Arkanoid {

  constructor(document, canvas) {
   this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas);
   this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
   this.points = 0;
   this.bar;
  }

  clear() {
   this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }

  draw(color = "#000000") {
   this.ctx.save();
   this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
   this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
   this.ctx.restore();
  }

  setupBar(...ref) {
   this.bar = new Bar(...ref);
  }

 }

 function setup() {

  arkanoid = new Arkanoid(document, "canvas");
  arkanoid.setupBar(arkanoid, arkanoid.ctx, (arkanoid.canvas.width / 2) - (25 / 2 | 0), arkanoid.canvas.height - 25, 25, 5, 10);
  ball = new Ball(arkanoid.ctx, arkanoid.canvas.width / 2, arkanoid.canvas.height / 2, 3);

 }

 function draw() {

  arkanoid.clear();
  arkanoid.draw();
  arkanoid.bar.draw();
  ball.draw();
  ball.move();
  ball.wallCollision();
  collision(ball, arkanoid.bar);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
 }

 setup();
 draw();
 document.addEventListener("click", () => { start(start) });
 //Para mover la barra empleo otra función modificada para que se vea mas fluido el movimiento, pero para no hacer mas largo el código pondre este
 document.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {

  if (ev.keyCode === 37) {
   if (arkanoid.bar.pos.x > 0) {
    arkanoid.bar.pos.x -= arkanoid.bar.speed;
   } else {
    arkanoid.bar.pos.x = 0;
   }
  } else if (ev.keyCode === 39) {
   if (arkanoid.bar.right < arkanoid.bar.ctx.canvas.width) {
    arkanoid.bar.pos.x += arkanoid.bar.speed;
   } else {
    arkanoid.bar.pos.x = arkanoid.bar.ctx.canvas.width - arkanoid.bar.w;
   }
  }

 });

}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

canvas{
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298991/canvas-js-calculate-new-velocity-vector-of-object-from-collision-with-slanted-s

Comment: Por favor ¿puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir tu código para que podamos ayudarte?

Comment: @enxaneta es que el código es muy largo y esta dividido... ya que hace parte de un juego, por eso intente describir el funciónamiento del como se mueve la pelota... voy a colocar lo basico (función de dibujado, la pelota, la función de colision y la clase barra), (pero en version corta). Lo que quiero hacer es que la pelota al chocar contra la barra salga disparada de manera correcta dependiendo del angulo y la velocidad que se le dio a la pelota.

Comment: Pregunta editada con el código (reducido y resumido)

Comment: Posdata, luego corrijo el pixelado del canvas, de momento lo tengo así como "simulador", como ejemplo, cuando uno con una pelota en la vida real golpea alguna esquina, dependiendo del angulo la pelota no sigue la misma dirección, si no que puede cambiar de dirección o no (Esto en las 3 coordenadas hablando de un espació 3D),en nuestro caso seria en un espació 2D,  eso es lo que necesito precisamente...

Comment: No acabo de entender la pregunta: la pelota rebota correctamente contra los bordes **y** contra el rectángulo que movemos con los cursores. ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: 2 errores:
- Primero: si la pelota choca exactamente con el borde izquierdo o derecho de la barra no cambia la direccion en x,esto hace que si seguimos el movimiento horizontal de la bola que no va a cambiar hasta chocar contra la pared o hasta que traspase del todo la barra hasta el otro extremo, la pelota quede dentro de la barra y rebote de arriba abajo dentro de la barra.

Comment: Sdo error:

- Colisionar con una esquina, en el juego original de arkanoid hace que la pelota cambie de dirección horizontal y tambien el angulo en el que la pelota rebota, esto hace que halla mas variabilidad de trayectorias en el juego, es precisamente a esto a lo que me refiero, si la pelota choca contra una esquina, deseo que la bola rebote de manera realista con un determinado angulo dependiendo de como fue golpeada por la esquina, en el juego arkanoid según el angulo en que fue golpeada la pelota las direcciónes en x y y, pueden cambiar o no.

Comment: Ese cambio depende de varios factores, uno de ellos es que tan arriba está la pelota con respecto a la barra cuando esta choca con ella, suponiendo que la  pelota esta callendo de arriba hacia abajo, entonces si en el momento que ella choca con la esquina el punto de origen de la pelota se encuentra mas bajo que la mitad de la barra, esta seguira su trayecto normal, pero de ser lo contrario la dirección en y cambiaria, esto mismo pasa al revez.

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacer una colision que distinga estas dos cosas para "simular", el rebote del arkanoid original, es decir, no se como detectar cuando estrictamente se colisiono con una esquina y dependiendo del angulo hacer que rebote con la trayectoria que debería de manera realista, y tampoco se como hacer lo que menciono en el comentario de arriba... (Es decir, logre hacer la colision vertical con la barra pero no la horizontal)